# How to iterate through multiple tags checking each tag value

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Hi I am a new bee to xml/xslt. Can someone help me on the below requirement
I have multiple tags with same name

```
<SO_ServiceType>XXXX</SO_ServiceType>
<SO_ServiceType>YYYY</SO_ServiceType>
<SO_ServiceType>ZZZZ</SO_ServiceType>
```

How to iterate and check  value of each tag

Answer (score 0):

This solution 'iterates' over each SO_ServiceType node...

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SO_ServiceType">
    <xsl:if test="text()='ZZZZ'">
      <sample>ZZZZ is the value</sample>
    </xsl:if>
    <node>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </node>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<node>XXXX</node>
<node>YYYY</node>
<sample>ZZZZ is the value</sample>
<node>ZZZZ</node>
```

Edit

If you only want to output 'true' in the result tree if the text() matches `A-70-00`you can do this:

```
  <xsl:template match="SO_ServiceType">
    <xsl:if test="text()='A-70-00'">true</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Remember that XSLT is a way to transform an input to an output. In XSLT you describe what rules needs to be applied to get the desired output result. Try to think what you want to happen with the input node instead of how you want to produce the output.

Comment: Hi rene, Thanks for your quick reply. I am trying to call a template which should return some value after iterating through the tags if a certain value is found.I am trying below piece but getting syntax error <xsl:template name="isCPESO">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Data/SO_Service_Type">
        <xsl:if test = "<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        = 'A-70-00'">
        <xsl:value-of select="true"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Comment: once the desired value is found i want to stop iterating and come out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments on [rene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17650438/592139) you probably don't need to "iterate" at all.  When you have an equality comparison in an XPath expression where one side or the other (or both) is a node set then the expression as a whole succeeds if *any* of the nodes in the set matches the value.  Thus

```
<xsl:if test="/Data/SO_Service_Type = 'A-70-00'">true</xsl:if>
```

will produce `true` if any of the `SO_Service_Type` elements have the value `A-70-00` - no `for-each` required.